# Why parallel diodes on the output of a switch-mode?

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply

I am looking at buck-boost converters on the Texas Instruments design tool, and multiple of these topologies have parallel diodes on the output. I cannot see any reason to do this.

Can anyone explain the purpose of paralleling D4 and D2 on the output?

[image: s]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parallel Schottky diodes are there to allow a higher forward current through the load. Usually done to prevent scenarios where the load current exceeds the maximum current rating of a single diode.

https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/basic-electronics/diode-in-parallel

EDIT: You can refer to the datasheet, page 23 for a similar design example. The diode packaging is shipped as a single component (MBRD1035). http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25118-q1.pdf

Comment: Nope. Notice in that article the two diodes have different curves? One diode will turn on first then runaway hogging all the current. They address this by adding resistors.

Comment: @FatDiode Pretty sure gusgus is right. That's not to say it's not bad design.

Comment: @FatDiode I don't understand. Where do you see the different curves? And where are the resistors? Do you mean Rfbt/Rfbb?

Comment: Current sharing can be a problem but usually these two diodes are on a single die so we can expect a decent sharing between the two dice: a) they are at the same operating temperature and b) their \$V_f\$ are probably quite close as they come from the same wafer lot. I've seen that in many hi-volume adapter designs and even paralleled diodes bridges sometime!

Comment: those parallel diodes may actually be in one package

Comment: @FatDiode You can easily check the BOM whether they're in one package / same die. Otherwise your comment regarding thermal runaway is correct.

Comment: This may reduce inductance.

Comment: @Huisman The component used for those specific diodes is a MBRD1035, so yes they are in one package/one die.

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense if they are in the same package. Interesting. Thanks for the lesson.